# font-face magical antialiasing how-to?

Tags: css, font-face, antialiasing

For months i've been curious how some websites were able to apply a antialiasing effect on normal fonts (fontfaces, not cufón, flash or anything else). In my Chrome Browser, CSS techniques like webkit font smoothing have absolutelly no effect - tried many ways.

But then, there is websites which fonts are antialiased and i dont know how. Look to those below, for example:

http://themes.bdayh.com/?theme=renad
http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/

You can see the font is antialiased and it is not by subpixel.

Could anybody please kill my curiosity and answer this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari only

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```